# Groupby a column and concatenate unique string values for multiple columns to create a single column

Tags: python, pandas-groupby, group-concat

I have a very large dataframe and I want to groupby the "NAME" column and  concatenate unique string values from the ID, ID2, ID3 and ID4 columns to create one column.

I have tried

```
df.groupby('NAME').apply(lambda x: x['ID'] + x['ID2'] + x['ID3'] + x['ID4'])
```

I have tried multiple `df.groupby.agg` with lambda functions but need to figure out a way to use `pd.unique` with string values.

```
NAME   Type    ID     ID2     ID3     ID4    MEMBERSHIP
Capg   Active  778    535     667     898     Global
Capg   Active  778    835     100     444     Blue
Capg   Active  778    535     667     898     Black
Doy   Active  246     8989    667     777     Silver
Doy   Active  266     8989    900     777     Silver
Doy   Active  266     8989    900     777     Silver
Art   Active  778     135     888     007     White
Art   Active  778     135     888     007     Silver
Art   Active  778     135     888     008     White
Art   Active  778     135     888     007     White
```

Desired Output:

```
NAME   Type    ID     ID2     ID3     ID4    MEMBERSHIP  MERGED_IDS
Capg   Active  778    535     667     898     Global     778, 535, 667, 898, 835, 100
Capg   Active  778    835     100     444     Blue       778, 535, 667, 898, 835, 100
Capg   Active  778    535     667     898     Black      778, 535, 667, 898, 835, 100
Doy   Active  246     8989    667     777     Silver     246, 8989, 667, 777, 266, 900
Doy   Active  266     8989    900     777     Silver     246, 8989, 667, 777, 266, 900
Doy   Active  266     8989    900     777     Silver     246, 8989, 667, 777, 266, 900
Art   Active  778     135     888     007     White      778, 135, 888, 007, 008
Art   Active  778     135     888     007     Silver     778, 135, 888, 007, 008
Art   Active  778     135     888     008     White      778, 135, 888, 007, 008
Art   Active  778     135     888     007     White      778, 135, 888, 007, 008
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your IDs into sets and then just get their union:

```
import io
import pandas as pd

data = """NAME   Type    ID     ID2     ID3     ID4    MEMBERSHIP
Capg   Active  778    535     667     898     Global
Capg   Active  778    835     100     444     Blue
Capg   Active  778    535     667     898     Black
Doy   Active  246     8989    667     777     Silver
Doy   Active  266     8989    900     777     Silver
Doy   Active  266     8989    900     777     Silver
Art   Active  778     135     888     007     White
Art   Active  778     135     888     007     Silver
Art   Active  778     135     888     008     White
Art   Active  778     135     888     007     White"""

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), sep=' ', skipinitialspace=True, dtype=str)

def group_IDs(x):
    return set(x['ID']) | set(x['ID2']) | set(x['ID3']) | set(x['ID4'])
grouped = df.groupby("NAME").apply(group_IDs)
grouped.name = "MERGED_IDS"
df.merge(grouped, left_on='NAME', right_index=True)
```

Resulting in:
[image]